# Match and change multiple date formats into one with Python Regex

Tags: python, regex, datetime, format

I need to implement a function in Python which is able to retrieve multiple date formats from input string, change them into one specific format and return the date only:

```
Format            Example Input String  

MMDDYYYY          foo.bar.02242015.txt
MMDDYY            foo.bar.022415.txt
MONCCYY           foo.bar.FEB2015.txt
YYYY-MM-DD        foo_bar_2015-02-01_2015-02-28.txt
YYYYMMDD          foo_bar_20150224.txt
MM_YY             foo_bar_02_15.txt
YYYYMMDD          foo_bar_20150224.txt
```

Output: just a fixed 8 digits date format (no foo, bar or txt):

```
YYYYMMDD (e.g. 20120524)
```

Example:

```
Input                     Output
foo.bar.02242015.txt  ->  20150224
```

Some requirements:

1. if date is missing, add the last day of the month:
   `foo_02_15.txt -> 20150228`
2. if year is 2 digits, change it to 4:
   `foo_02_24_16.txt -> 20160224`
3. valid year is current or previous year, for now:  2016 or 2015
4. if month is not number, e.g. FEB, change it to 2 digit number:
   `foo.FEB2015.txt -> 20150228`
5. Format 'YYYY-MM-DD' always contains two dates, fetch the second one:
   `foo_2015-02-01_2015-02-28.txt -> 20150228`

Anyone know how to do it with Regex in Python? Or what is the best practice to do it?

Comment: There will be cases where MMDDYYYY and YYYYMMDD will be indistinguishable from one another (e.g., 12251104 can be 25th December, 1104 [MMDDYYYY] or 4th November 1225 [YYYYMMMDD])

Comment: This question will use 10% Regex + 90% programming.

Comment: A valid year which is current or previous year needs to be checked. So year    1104 or 1225 wont be a valid input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import re
import time
import datetime
import calendar

p = re.compile(ur'(?<=\.|_)([A-Z\d+_-]*?([A-Z\d+_-]{0,10}))(?=\.)')
test_str = u"Format            Example Input String  \n\nMMDDYYYY          foo.bar.02242015.txt\nMMDDYY            foo.bar.022415.txt\nMONCCYY           foo.bar.FEB2015.txt\nYYYY-MM-DD        foo_bar_2015-02-01_2015-02-28.txt\nYYYYMMDD          foo_bar_20150224.txt\nMM_YY             foo_bar_02_15.txt\nYYYYMMDD          foo_bar_20150224.txt"
def changedate(date):
    try:
        t = time.strptime(date,'%m%d%Y')
    except:
        pass
    try:
        t = time.strptime(date,'%m%d%y')
    except:
        pass
    try:
        t = time.strptime(date,'%b%Y')
        lastday = calendar.monthrange(int(t.tm_year), int(t.tm_mon))[1]
        t = time.strptime(date + str(lastday),'%b%Y%d')
    except:
        pass
    try:
        t = time.strptime(date,'%m_%y')
        lastday = calendar.monthrange(int(t.tm_year), int(t.tm_mon))[1]
        t = time.strptime(date + str(lastday),'%m_%y%d')
    except:
        pass        
    try:
        t = time.strptime(date,'%Y-%m-%d')
    except:
        pass
    try:
        r = time.strftime("%Y%m%d",t)
        return r
    except:
        pass
    return date
test_str = re.sub(p,lambda m: changedate(m.group(2)), test_str)
print test_str
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oE1gM2/2)

Input

```
Format            Example Input String  

MMDDYYYY          foo.bar.02242015.txt
MMDDYY            foo.bar.022415.txt
MONCCYY           foo.bar.FEB2015.txt
YYYY-MM-DD        foo_bar_2015-02-01_2015-02-28.txt
YYYYMMDD          foo_bar_20150224.txt
MM_YY             foo_bar_02_15.txt
YYYYMMDD          foo_bar_20150224.txt
```

Output:

```
Format            Example Input String  

MMDDYYYY          foo.bar.20150224.txt
MMDDYY            foo.bar.20150224.txt
MONCCYY           foo.bar.20150228.txt
YYYY-MM-DD        foo_bar_20150228.txt
YYYYMMDD          foo_bar_20150224.txt
MM_YY             foo_bar_20150228.txt
YYYYMMDD          foo_bar_20150224.txt
```

**Explanation**:

E.g.

Input

`foo_bar_2015-02-01_2015-02-28.txt`

So

`(?<=\.|_)([A-Z\d+_-]*?([A-Z\d+_-]{0,10}))(?=\.)`

Regex to capture date string in to group `m`

```
1.  [182-203]   `2015-02-01_2015-02-28`
2.  [193-203]   `2015-02-28`    

m.group(0) = 2015-02-01_2015-02-28
m.group(1) = 2015-02-01_2015-02-28
m.group(2) = 2015-02-28
```

Then
`lambda m: changedate(m.group(2))` to re-format datetime

So

`2015-02-28` can not pass others as

```
    try:
        t = time.strptime(date,'%m%d%Y')
    except:
        pass
```

But pass only this block

```
    try:
        r = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d",t)
        return r
    except:
        pass
```

Then format it

```
try:
    r = time.strftime("%Y%m%d",t)
    return r
except:
    pass
```

Comment: Can you explain 're.sub(p,lambda m: changedate(m.group(0)), test_str)' a little bit? Also I updated the question with the output requirement and a special case contains two matched date

Comment: @Li' added some explanation, hope it makes sense.

Comment: thanks for your update and explanation. I think you mean pass block "%Y-%m-%d". That repeat limit solved my problem. Btw the regex101 tool is great!

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE2** Please try the following approach (python 2.7):

```
import re
import calendar

INPUT = ['foo.bar.02242015.txt',
        'foo.bar.022415.txt',
        'foo.bar.FEB2015.txt',
        'foo_bar_2015-02-01_2015-02-28.txt',
        'foo_bar_20150224.txt',
        'foo_bar_02_15.txt',
        'foo_bar_20150224.txt' ]
P1 = r'(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])((?:19|20)?\d{2})'
P2 = r'[A-Z]{3}[12]\d{3}|[12]\d{3}-(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])_?|(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])_[12]\d'
MONTHS = ['JAN','FEB','MAR','APR','MAY','JUN','JUL','AUG','SEP','OCT','NOV','DEC']

def StrFormat(date_string):
    m2 = re.findall(P2, date_string)
    if m2:
        for m in m2:
            if len(m) == 5:
                month, year = m.split('_')[0], '20' +  m.split('_')[1]
                last_day = calendar.monthrange(int(year), int(month))[1]
                date_string = re.sub(P2, year+month+ str(last_day), date_string, 1)
            elif len(m) == 7:
                month, year = str(MONTHS.index(m[0:3]) + 1).zfill(2), m[3:]
                last_day = calendar.monthrange(int(year), int(month))[1]
                date_string = re.sub(P2, year+month+ str(last_day), date_string, 1)
            elif len(m) == 10:
                date_string =  re.sub(P2, m.replace('-', ''), date_string, 1)
            elif len(m) > 5:
                date_string =  re.sub(P2, '', date_string, 1)

    m1 = re.findall(P1, date_string)
    if m1:
        for m in m1:
            if len(m[2]) == 2:
                date_string = re.sub(P1, r'20\3\1\2', date_string, 1)
            elif len(m[2]) == 4:
                date_string = re.sub(P1, r'\3\1\2', date_string, 1)
            elif len(m) > 2:
                date_string = re.sub(P1, '', date_string, 1)
    return date_string


for i in INPUT:
    print i.ljust(35), '->', StrFormat(i).rjust(20)
```

Output:

```
foo.bar.02242015.txt                -> foo.bar.20150224.txt
foo.bar.022415.txt                  -> foo.bar.20150224.txt
foo.bar.FEB2015.txt                 -> foo.bar.20150228.txt
foo_bar_2015-02-01_2015-02-28.txt   -> foo_bar_20150228.txt
foo_bar_20150224.txt                -> foo_bar_20150224.txt
foo_bar_02_15.txt                   -> foo_bar_20150228.txt
foo_bar_20150224.txt                -> foo_bar_20150224.txt
```

Btw: It is indeed `10% Regex + 90% programming` as suggested by noob :-)

Comment: I just updated the question. How to handle the special case which contains two matched dates?

Comment: @Li': please try the updated version to see if it suits your needs.

Comment: thanks for your update. But the return value I want is just 8 digits date. So it would be '20150228' instead of 'foo_bar_20150201_20150228.txt'